# AngularJS: How efficient is it to use mouseenter and mouseleave to change hover color on rows in a table?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking to implement something like this on a table that I have with about 1,000 rows:

```
<tr 
    ng-class="{red-background: hover}" 
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
    ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
      <td>xyz</td>
</tr>
```

Can someone tell me is this efficient or will there be a problem because it's checking for mouseenter and leave on some many rows? One more question. If I implement for the rows will the scope of each "hover" be different and only apply to that row?

Comment: How many rows are you displaying: tens, hundreds, thousands, millions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using AngularJS for changing the background color of a row when hover?

Can't you use just CSS:

```
tr:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You have a very good point. I guess I'm spending too much time thinking AngularJS these days. Thanks